# Default today's date in date picker using react js without using DatePicker component

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

In my TODO list app I have datepicker field named startDate for which I want the default date to be current date.

Here is the code:
I have tried define defaultValue but that is giving me error as date not defined.

Picker code:

```
                  <Label for="start">Start Date</Label>
                  <Input
                    type="date"
                    name="startDate"
                    //defaultValue= {this.state.activeItem.date}
                    value={this.state.activeItem.startDate}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                  <Label for="end">End Date</Label>
                  <Input
                    type="date"
                    name="endDate"
                    value={this.state.activeItem.endDate}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
```

This is the code I have written to fetch default date:

```
     curr.setDate(curr.getDate());
     var date = curr.toISOString().substr(0,10);
```

I am not getting where to perform the above operation inside constructor or render method.

Here's the complete class code

```
export default class CustomModal extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          activeItem: this.props.activeItem
        };
      }
      handleChange = e => {
        let { name, value } = e.target;
        if (e.target.type === "checkbox") {
          value = e.target.checked;
        }
        const activeItem = { ...this.state.activeItem, [name]: value };
        this.setState({ activeItem });
      };
      render() {
        const { toggle, onSave } = this.props;
        return (
          <Modal isOpen={true} toggle={toggle}>
            <ModalHeader toggle={toggle}> Todo Item </ModalHeader>
            <ModalBody>
              <Form>
                <FormGroup>
                  <Label for="title">Title</Label>
                  <Input
                    type="text"
                    name="title"
                    value={this.state.activeItem.title}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    placeholder="Enter Todo Title"
                  />
                  <FormGroup>
                  <Label for="start">Start Date</Label>
                  <Input
                    type="date"
                    name="startDate"
                    //defaultValue= {this.state.activeItem.date}
                    value={this.state.activeItem.startDate}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                  <Label for="end">End Date</Label>
                  <Input
                    type="date"
                    name="endDate"
                    value={this.state.activeItem.endDate}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                </FormGroup>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                  <Label for="description">Description</Label>
                  <Input
                    type="text"
                    name="description"
                    value={this.state.activeItem.description}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    placeholder="Enter Todo description"
                  />
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup check>
                  <Label for="completed">
                    <Input
                      type="checkbox"
                      name="completed"
                      checked={this.state.activeItem.completed}
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                    Completed
                  </Label>
                </FormGroup>
              </Form>
            </ModalBody>
            <ModalFooter>
              <Button color="success" onClick={() => onSave(this.state.activeItem)}>
                Save
              </Button>
            </ModalFooter>
          </Modal>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: what is the type of `this.state.activeItem.startDate` ? Is it a `date` or a `string` ?

Comment: it is a string type

Comment: what is the format ? is it `YYYY-MM-DD` ?

Comment: format is MM-DD-YY

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Value `MM-DD-YY` doesn't seem to be a valid format, you should try with the `YYYY-MM-DD` format

Comment: But the issue is not format I am unable to display current date

Comment: you should init `this.state.activeItem.startDate` (in the contructor) with the current date `new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
export default class CustomModal extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        var date = new Date();

        var formatedDate = `${date.getMonth()+1}-${date.getDate()}-${date.getFullYear()}`

        this.state = {
          // Use object destructuring to create a new object with the default value
          activeItem: {
            startDate: formatedDate
            // But if the startDate exists on the prop item, it will be replaced.
            ...this.props.activeItem
          }
        };
      }
      //...
```

But it only sets the default value once, if want to save it to use later, just add it to the state and use the `defaultValue` as you tried before.

```
export default class CustomModal extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // Assuming that this code gives you the date on the right format

        var date = new Date();

        var formatedDate = `${date.getMonth()+1}-${date.getDate()}-${date.getFullYear()}`

        this.state = {
          startingDate: formatedDate,
          activeItem: {
...
          <Input
            type="date"
            name="startDate"
            defaultValue={this.state.startingDate}
            value={this.state.activeItem.startDate}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Can you also tell me how to convert the format to MM-DD-YYY

Comment: I recommend using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), but if you can't, do this `var formatedDate = \`${date.getMonth()+1}-${date.getDate()}-${date.getFullYear()}\` `

Comment: Don't forget to add 1 to the month, they starts from 0!

Comment: I tried above mentioned code inside render() method. I am getting an error ```TypeError: date.getMonth is not a function```

Comment: Done, just check in the constructor.

Comment: ```constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        var curr = new Date();
        curr.setDate(curr.getDate());
        var date = curr.toISOString().substr(0,10);
        var formatedDate = `${date.getMonth()+1}-${date.getDate()}-${date.getFullYear()}`
        this.state = {
          startingDate: formatedDate,  
          activeItem: {
              ...this.props.activeItem,
              // by Using object destructuring creating a new object with the default value
              //startDate: date
          }
        };
      } ```

still getting the same error

Comment: My bad, didn't realize that the date variable already was converted, editing it again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193866/discussion-between-amnah-khatun-and-toug).

Answer (score 0):

use this line of code in your application

```
const abc = this.state.startDate.getDate() + "/" + (this.state.startDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + this.state.startDate.getFullYear()
```

you can give any name in place of `startDate`. it will give `dd/mm/yyyy`